# Where can I find django(ORM) practice problems?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm really finding it very difficult to source practice problems for Django and its ORMs. I've heard Mosh's paid course has such exercises. I'm just getting started with Django mostly referring to youtube and its official documentation. I hope one of you who reads this could help me out.

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask.

Thanks in advance!